# Overridden Class Only Offers Static Methods

Tags: android

I have a class that overrides TextView however if I try to use any of the member functions of either my class or TextView I get an error message in Eclipse stating  "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method ##MEMBER FUNCTION## from the type View". Where ##MEMBER FUNCTION## is the method I am calling i.e. setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams). If I look in the suggestions dialog only the static methods are offered.

I have tried cutting my class down too;

```
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyClass extends TextView {

    public MyClass(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

But I still get the same errors.

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Comment: What is the code that raises the error. I am interested in that.

Comment: Any use of a member method of an instance of MyClass.

Comment: Can you bring a snippet please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're doing something like TextView.method() calls instead of textView.method() where textView is an instance of TextView.  the error does not match your post title at all -- it's the opposite.

Comment: What a numpty I am, you are of course right. That serves me right for coding to the point of exhaustion. I knew as soon as I looked this morning.  
I had made a class, then an instance of that class and then used the class name rather than the instance name when I used it.  
(This does only offer the static methods though as the title says :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not calling the method with TextView.* in front.

For example, not:

```
TextView.getWidth();
```

but instead, simply:

```
getWidth();
```